# Check for data availability before calling ee.ImageCollection.filterDate

Tags: google-earth-engine

Hey fellow EE developers!

I am currently working with the Dynamic World data set and am analyzing different locations for a set time range (2016-2022).

However, at some locations it seems data is missing, so EE returns:

`Image.eq: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1.`

Minimal reproducible example (js, requires Google EE):

```
    var startDate = "2017-01-01";
    var endDate = "2018-01-01";
    var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([80.67174096,29.92240786]);
    var dw = ee.ImageCollection("GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1").filterDate(startDate,endDate).filterBounds(geometry);
    print(dw.size());
```

I thought about running a try/except, but that didn't work. Can someone think how I can check for data availability before calling the ImageCollection.filterDate() method?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: are you messaging EE developers or the stack overflow community ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @D.L thanks, I provided a small snippet for the js engine.